# Watir file upload window preventing from further redirection

Tags: ruby, file, upload, window, watir

When I upload photos using watir with this code on windows:

```
file_input.set("#{Dir.pwd}/photos/" +'image.jpg')
```

uploading works okay, but a dialog windows appears, and it prevents the script from redirecting to the next page. I don't know how to close it, and I need to find a way to handle it. `browser.windows.size` shows that there is only one window, and I'm stuck. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it a browser javascript alert dialog, or a Windows (Operating System) dialog? What does it say?

Comment: If it's a regular JS alert dialog: https://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/. If it's something weird: `send_keys` is kind of hacky, but how about `tab` (to window OK/close button), then `send_keys :space` or `:enter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Windows dialog, it takes over the focus, you cannot click anything else (Watir goes on, but redirection at the end is aborted).

I found solution by ***preventing default behavior*** of input element:

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('file').onclick = function(e){ e.preventDefault() } ")
```

I don't know if it is good solution but it works fine for me (if not, please notify me), I hope that it would help someone.